# Byte streams and related stuff

Tags: java

I have several questions related to what byte streams are, how they emmm...operate. If you have some newb-friendly links, it would fit the best.

1) When i save byte stream into some txt (e.g. writeInt method), i get gibberish characters. Where do they come from? Text editor tries to decode the bytes, but why unsuccessfully? At the same time `writeBytes()` from `DataOutputStream` class also writes strings as a sequence of bytes, but this time it shows up as characters in text editor. Why?

2) What `DataOutputStream` filter is used for, what does it add? It is said that `DataOutputStream`  enables various types (`int`, `double`...) to be written directly from the stream. What does it mean?

4) If i have 2 docx 1000 characters each, 1st uses English characters, 2nd e.g. Russian characters. Shouldn't Russian document be bigger (since as i understand all these strange letters may take more than 1 byte). But it doesn't seem to be like this.

5) What is the difference between byte and character streams in terms of implementation -- both save sequence of bytes, but character streams divide it into pieces? How is that accomplished?

Thank you!

Comment: 1.) Give an example  2.) read the doc 3.) what did you expect 4.) Read about character encoding 5.) Again, read about encoding.

Comment: 4) All characters in Java represented as 16 bits or 2 bytes.

Comment: from where you are getting byte stream? are you getting from network?

Comment: if you read your stream from a source then take 2 byte each time and convert it to int and write the value to file. use   writeChar(int v)

Comment: what is the point to answer "read about encoding?" If you have some good links, please, share, if not, yes, thank you, I am reading in parallel, but haven't figured it out yet. about 3) i didn't know that int represents integers up to 2^31, bad question indeed

Comment: You should read about [Character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). Data is just bits of 0's and 1's, text is characters saved as 0's and 1's in some encoding.

Comment: all these are theoretical questions

Answer (score 5):

Java holds a conceptual distinction between:

- Binary data: `byte[], InputStream, OutputStream`
- Text (Unicode): `String, char, Reader, Writer`
- Bridge between them: `InputStreamReader, OutputStreamWriter, String.getBytes(charset), new String(bytes, charset)`

An int consists of 4 bytes, for instance 0, 0, 2, 12 for 2*256+12 = 524. In a file these bytes are not recognizable.
A text representation of `Integer.toString(524)` = "524" in ASCII or almost any character set would be as:

```
byte[] bytes = "542".getBytes("UTF-8"); // Three bytes: 53, 50, 52
```

A **DataOutputStream** is a special (binary data) OutputStream for Java objects. It can also output a String, as UTF-8 bytes, which are human recognizable, in a mess of binary values.

The **docx** format (as does the **odt** format) is a zipped directory with content as XML file. XML generally is in UTF-8, and for Cyrillic that would be a bit more. The compression however muddles the issue.

**Unicode** is a numbering of all characters fitting in [0, 2<sup>24</sup>). There is the multi-byte encoding **UTF-8** for Unicode, that for the first 128 ASCII characters uses one byte, and for the rest multiple bytes. In those multibyte sequences no `\` or so can be found (high-bits set), which is comfortable. Also the byte 0 may redundantly written as multi-byte sequence, which is nice for C based software like operating systems, that interprete a 0 byte as string terminator (not so Java). **UTF-16** uses two bytes, and with that can handle almost all non-Asian scripts. If the Unicode number is higher than 2<sup>16</sup> a similar mechanism is used, of char sequences for one Unicode char. There is UTF-16LE (little endian) and UTF-16BE (big endian) for order of the two bytes. Above in the int example big-endian was used. Intel processors/Windows uses little endian.

---

***After comment:***

A byte is a unit of 8 bits (0 or 1), and its values are 00000000 (=0), ..., 11111111 (=255). ASCII characters assign some character to a number between 0 and 127, like:

```
32 = ' '    64 = '@'
48 = '0'    65 = 'A'
49 = '1'    66 = 'B'
```

On binary numbers see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number).

Comment: ok, if decide to write numbers from 1 to 10 into txt as bytes, and then i open txt with notepad, what would i see? Why? Also i didn't quite understand  0, 0, 2, 12 for 2*256+12 = 524. Thank you for your answer